# cakephp render element with data

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am trying to render an element and refresh it.  So, when a user clicks a button, it calls an ajax function that calls a php function.  this function adds data to a database.  This all works.  But, now I want to re-render the element with the new data.  This is what I have so far:

```
public function add_role() {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    if ($this->request->data['Role']) {
        $this->Role->create();
        if ($this->Role->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->set('roles', $this->Role->find('all'));
            $this->render('/Elements/role_table');
        }else{
            return  "Failed Insert";
        }

    }
}
```

But this causes the element to just be displayed twice in the page (although the new one is updated).  How do I do this correctly or remove the original element?

Thanks

Edit: added element and jQuery

Element:

```
<?php
echo'
<div style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: none; height: 100%; width:350px;" id="roleTable">
<table style=" border:1px solid black; width:300px;  ">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Role</th>
    </tr>
   ';

foreach ($roles as $role) {
     echo '
     <tr>
        <td>';
            echo $role["Role"]["id"];
        echo '
        </td>
        <td>';
            echo $role["Role"]["role_name"];
            echo'
        </td>

    </tr>';
}
 echo'
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
        Add Role:
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>

    <td colspan="2">
        <form id="ajaxPostForm">
            <input type="text" name="data[Role][role_name]" style="width: 60%"
                   required="required" id="tbRole" >
            <input value="Save" type="button" onclick="save_role();">
        </form>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div id="addRoleStatus">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table></div>';
```

jQuery for original insert:

```
function save_role() {
    var role= $('#tbRole').val();
    var base=$('#ajaxPostForm');
    var params=base.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Roles/add_role',
        data: params,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'HTML',
        beforeSend: function(){
        },
        success: function (html){
             $('#addRoleStatus').html(html);       
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: You should be posting your jquery here, as the cakePHP part sounds like it's working.  But, if you replace the content of the parent of the element you're displaying with the data you get from your ajax call, $('#parentElement').html(data); it should replace the old version with the new.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I'm not sure that I follow, though.  I thought that  $this->render('/elements/role_table'); would take care of the rendering( and in fact, it does, it just doesnt render correctly).  What jquery would I need?  The only jQuery I have is this:  A user submits a record to a table.  This is done with jQuery.  I then want to update the view to reflect the added/deleted/edited record after there is a successful insert into the table. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Just in case, though, Ive added the jQuery and the element code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found something here with jQuery: `$('#addRoleStatus').html(html);`

The element you are echoing is also contain a `div#addRoleStatus` and in your AJAX success you are setting the echoed element to the same `div#addRoldStatus`.

I think this is point it chaos.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the original DOM element rendered by the first render call with jQuery on the AJAX update with .remove().

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've added the code for my element and jQuery.  I tried to use the .Remove() code but it ends up removing the whole element.  I was under the impression that cakes  $this->render('/Elements/role_table'); code would re-render the entire block, though.  Any help would be great.